# oracle query returns 0 records when args passed

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run an sql like this:

```
select * from tbl_emp where emp_name like '%%'
```

It gives me all records.
When I run it like this:

```
select * from tbl_emp where emp_name like : arg_emp_name
```

Then execute the query, then pass arg_emp_name as `'%%'`, it returns 0 records.
Why is this behavior?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you include the single quotes in your bound variable? You shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**:-

As per the comments obtained for the answer, it is clear that the oracle does not see any difference between the literal and the binding variable values. The meaning does not change as I had mentioned in my old answer. The answer from @Conard seems logical.

**OLD ANSWER**:-

When you pass the `'%%'` as an argument, it is literally taken as those string and they lose out on special meaning which they have when used in the query.

It means, the query will search your column for data containing `'%%'` instead of treating it as a LIKE. Hence you get 0 records.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way would happen is if you escaped the `%` . e.g. `\%\%`. Here's an example where you might to do that `EXEC :arg_emp_name := 'Test\%%'; SELECT 'Test' FROM  DUAL WHERE 'Test%%Test' like  :arg_emp_name`

Comment: your answer may have helped the OP but it is wrong. Oracle sees no difference between a literal (e.g. `'%%'`) and a bind variable set to the same value. In this case, the cause is that the bind variable is being set to a *different* value.

Comment: @Jeffrey, @Conard - Yeah. No problem guys. This is new for me to know as well. Not sure how this answer could solve OP's problem too. @Kaushik - I too really think, the answer from @Conard seems logical.

Comment: @Jeffrey,@Conard - Have edited my answer guys. Now its left to OP to do the rest. :)

Answer (score 5):

That should work fine. For example the following returns the same number of records as no `where` clause

```
EXEC :arg_emp_name := '%%';

SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE  :arg_emp_name
```

If you add more to the string

```
   EXEC :arg_emp_name := '%ABC%';

   SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE  :arg_emp_name
```

only Tables with ABC in their name are returned

However I would note that there's no space between `:` and `arg_emp_name`

Having that space there causes the error

```
Error starting at line 4 in command:
SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE  : arg_emp_name
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
01008. 00000 -  "not all variables bound"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```